# 2-DCT Image compression matlab

Tags: matlab, image-compression, dct

**Problem:**

I tried implementing Discrete Cosine Transformation compression using matlab.
Input image would a jpg image (Lena) having a size 512 X 512.

There are two stages namely compression and decompression.

**Compression and Quantization:**

The input image is converted to YCbCr component. Then Y component is taken up 
for compression. Further DCT will quantized.

**Quantization and Decompression:**

The quantized image is undergoes dequantization for decompression.

**Issues:**

Rectangular boxes are spotted in the decompressed version of the image. Is anything wrong with the code?
For your inference, below are the sample input and output images  and followed by the matlab code.

**Input image:**

[image]

**Y Component in YCbCr:**

[image]

**Output image:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
I = imread('lena512.jpg');
figure, imshow(I);
% Y = I;
YCbCr = rgb2ycbcr(I);
figure, imshow(YCbCr);
Y = YCbCr(:,:, 1);
figure, imshow(Y);
[h, w] = size(Y);
r = h/8;
c = w/8;

s = 1;
q50 = [16 11 10 16 24 40 51 61;
       12 12 14 19 26 58 60 55;
       14 13 16 24 40 57 69 56;
       14 17 22 29 51 87 80 62;
       18 22 37 56 68 109 103 77;
       24 35 55 64 81 104 113 92;
       49 64 78 87 103 121 120 101;
       72 92 95 98 112 100 103 99];


%    COMPRESSION
for i=1:r
    e = 1;
    for j=1:c
        block = Y(s:s+7,e:e+7);
        cent = double(block) - 128;
        for m=1:8
            for n=1:8
                if m == 1
                    u = 1/sqrt(8);
                else
                    u = sqrt(2/8);
                end
                if n == 1
                    v = 1/sqrt(8);
                else
                    v = sqrt(2/8);
                end
                comp = 0;
                for x=1:8
                    for y=1:8
                        comp = comp + cent(x, y)*(cos((((2*(x-1))+1)*(m-1)*pi)/16))*(cos((((2*(y-1))+1)*(n-1)*pi)/16));
                    end
                end

                F(m, n) = v*u*comp;
            end
        end

        for x=1:8
            for y=1:8
                cq(x, y) = round(F(x, y)/q50(x, y));
            end
        end
        Q(s:s+7,e:e+7) = cq;
        e = e + 8;
    end
    s = s + 8;
end


% % % % % % % % % % % % % % %     
% % DECOMPRESSION
% % % % % % % 
s = 1;
for i=1:r
    e = 1;
    for j=1:c
        cq = Q(s:s+7,e:e+7);
        for x=1:8
            for y=1:8
                DQ(x, y) = q50(x, y)*cq(x, y); 
            end
        end
         for m=1:8
            for n=1:8
                if m == 1
                    u = 1/sqrt(8);
                else
                    u = sqrt(2/8);
                end
                if n == 1
                    v = 1/sqrt(8);
                else
                    v = sqrt(2/8);
                end
                comp = 0;
                for x=1:8
                    for y=1:8
                        comp = comp + u*v*DQ(x, y)*(cos((((2*(x-1))+1)*(m-1)*pi)/16))*(cos((((2*(y-1))+1)*(n-1)*pi)/16));
                    end
                end

                bf(m, n) = round(comp)+128;
            end

         end

         Org(s:s+7,e:e+7) = bf;
         e = e + 8;
    end
    s = s + 8;
end


imwrite(Y, 'F:\workouts\phd\jpeg\input.jpg');
imwrite(uint8(Org), 'F:\workouts\phd\jpeg\output.jpg');
return;
```

Can you suggest me where the error is? It would be helpful.